# ExecuteNonQuery Takes more time to delete nearly 7000 records, How can I improve performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am executing below query using ADO.NET. It takes nearly 60s to execute. At the same time when I run the query in SQL Server management studio, it takes only 1 second. Why is the huge difference and How can I improve the performance?

I tried the Stored procedure also. it is also taking nearly 60s.

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table1]
  WHERE ID = @Id ; -- nearly 600 records

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table2]
  WHERE ID = @Id ; -- nearly 6500 records

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table3]
  WHERE ID = @Id;  -- 1 record


COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRAN
THROW
END CATCH
");
```

Comment: then use the store procedure instead. revise the code, add a new parameter @id to the store procedure, and call the store procedure from your code with the list of ids. rather than inserting the query inside a loop to be executed on each id.

Comment: @iSR5 I don't see a loop; I see a PK/FK-based delete - looks fine; OP  already says they've tried an SP, and hint: SPs don't change anything major (since something like 2003?)

Comment: Is it possible that this is a bad plan cache due to parameter sniffing? can you try adding `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Id UNKNOWN))` to the three deletes?

Comment: question: what is `@Id` here? meaning: is it `int`? or `nvarchar(something)`? or... - it can be important

Comment: `7000` is actually not that much to take that long.

Comment: Are Table1, 2 and 3 heaps? If no, is ID the clustered index key of these tables? If yes, is there non-clustered index by ID? Are there after delete triggers on these tables? Are there cascade delete foreign keys to these tables? If yes, are the fields in the child tables indexed? Are there after delete triggers on the detailed tables too?

Comment: @SeM I'd be disappointed if it took 6 seconds... 7000 rows should be sub-second

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right.

Comment: @Irf92 what is the ID column in all those tables? Is it indexed? Is it a primary key? What does the *execution plan* for that query look like? You can't fix missing index issues by modifying the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ID column is the primary key of table3 and the foreign key to other 2 tables.

Comment: @Irf92 that doesn't say anything about *indexes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this below. This is happening because of Parameter Sniffing. To overcome this issue, There are 4 methods

- OPTION (RECOMPILE)
- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE=VALUE))
- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE UNKNOWN))
- Use local variables

Below I have used the 4th method to fix this issue. [referred](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY
Declare @Id int = @PId ; -- passing the parameter only here
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE ID = @Id ; -- nearly 600 records

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table2]
WHERE ID = @Id ; -- nearly 6500 records

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table3]
WHERE ID = @Id;  -- 1 record


COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRAN
THROW
END CATCH
");
```

Thanks for everyone to make the better answer

Comment: Note: this isn't a fix for parameter sniffing - all you've done is change the query, so now you've sniffed/cached a *different* initial value; the *fix* is - as I put in the comments - to use the `UNKNOWN` option

Comment: That query doesn't change anything. The parameter is passed only once in both queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it works for me. the execution plan of the SQL server is different for both cases.

Comment: @Irf92 no, it worked for that parameter you used. Those are the very symptoms of parameter sniffing. Once you use a different parameter you'll run into the same problem.